# AngularUI Timepicker - Select time in popup

Tags: angularjs, popup, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, timepicker

We are using AngularUI timepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for selecting time
After integration, I was not able to select time and set format but I need to show the same in a popup just like datepicker.
User will click on time icon and then a popup will appear for time selection. Tired using below code but did not worked.

`<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-timepicker-popup ng-model="mytime" is-open="popup1.opened" ng-change="changed()" 
hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" ng-required="true"  close-text="Close" />`

I have made a plunker for the same - http://plnkr.co/edit/yv3xT8KbP6pD7tV46Clf?p=preview

How do I show the time selection in popup ?

Ref - http://plnkr.co/edit/S8UqwvXNGmDcPXV7a0N3?p=preview (See Pick a Time option)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use both the timepicker and modal together.

```
<p class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mytime"  />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></button>
  </span>
</p>
```

and in the controller:

```
 $scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    time: function () {
      return $scope.mytime;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.mytime = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

};

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6cSmKvv9Ul4Euk6FStyh?p=preview) with an example

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am already including ui-bootstrap file and just for timepicker, its not advisable to include another datetimepicker.js file. Can you change it to work with angular-ui ?

Comment: ui-bootstrap doesn't offer a time picker popup that I can find.  please advise.

Comment: and that is where the customization lie. Can we have some way  to show the time picker in popup ?

Comment: I updated the example to show how to use both uib-modal and uib-timepicker to get the desired results.  it will be much more involved than the datepicker popup they've created a directive for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) directive where you can define the content template.